# Finding $x$ values of $\cos 6x + 1 = \frac{3}{2} + \frac {1}{2} \cos 3x $

Tags: trigonometry

> Solve $$\cos 6x + 1 = \frac{3}{2} + \frac {1}{2} \cos 3x $$ for $0^\circ<x<120^\circ$

I simplify it to

$$2 \cos 6x + 2 = 3 + \cos 3x $$

There is $\cos 6x $ and $\cos 3x$ how do I merge them together? To solve the equation from $0^\circ$ to $120^\circ$?

Comment: Use the double-angle identity

Comment: $x=0$ is a solution, but I think you want something more interesting.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Use the identity

$$\cos 2y=2\cos^{2}y-1$$

with $y=3x$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I got...(EDIT: $3 \cos 3x$ is incorrect in the third line; the correct quantity is $\cos 3x$.).

$$\cos 6x + 1 = \frac {3}{2} + \frac {1}{2} \cos 3x$$

Multiplying by $2$ we get

$$2 \cos 6x + 2 = 3 + \cos 3x$$

Swapping constants and bringing over $\cos 3x$ we then get

$$2 \cos 6x - \cos 3x = 1$$

Using the double angle identity $\cos 6x = 2 \cos^2 3x - 1$ we get

$$4 \cos^2 3x - 2 -  \cos 3x = 1$$

Adding 2 to each side gives us

$$4 \cos^2 3x -  \cos 3x = 3$$

Now we can factor out $\cos 3x$ on the left to get

$$\cos 3x (4 \cos 3x - 1) = 3$$

We now have two equations.  Since $\cos 3x = 3$ has no solution, we concentrate on $4 \cos 3x - 1 = 3$; this yields

$$4 \cos 3x = 4$$ or $$\cos 3x = 1$$

Taking the inverse cosine of both sides we get

$$3x = 0 + 360\times k$$ (k in degrees)

and then dividing by 3 we get

$$x = 0 + 120 \times k$$

For the condition $x \in (0, 120)$ we arrive at the answer, $$\bbox [yellow] {x=120}$$.

CHECK: $\cos 6(120) + 1 \rightarrow 1 + 1 \rightarrow 2$ and $\frac {3}{2} + \frac {1}{2} \cos 360 \rightarrow \frac {3}{2} + \frac {1}{2} \rightarrow \frac {4}{2} \rightarrow 2 \checkmark$

**Alternative answer (as suggested by Lab Bhatterchajee):**

Instead of factoring out as above, substitute $u = \cos 3x$ and subtract $3$ from both sides gives us

$$4u^2 - u + 3 = 0$$

Using the quadratic equation $x = \frac {-b \pm \sqrt {b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ we have

$$u = \frac {-1 \pm \sqrt {1^2-4(4)(-3)}}{(2)(4)}$$, which leaves us with

$$u = \frac {1 \pm 7}{8}$$

Bringing back $u = \cos 3x$ we have two solutions:

$$\cos 3x = -\frac {3}{4}, 1$$

Since we are looking for values from $0$ to $120$, we discard the negative value and continue on from $\cos 3x = 1$ from before - yielding the same answer as above, avoiding an extraneous solution.

Comment: Why don't we  Use quadratic equation here?

Comment: Where did ur $3$ from $3 \cos x$ in the 3rd step come from

Comment: Lab - that works a treat and was much quicker!  I've added your suggestion to my edit.
user175089 - good catch - I've corrected it to $\cos 3x$.